# How to split text in Python 3

Tags: python, split, readlines

My assignment is to open a file and to open a text file and make a list of the all the words used. I am able to open, read, and close the file, however, when I try to split, I get the following error below.

What does this mean and any suggestions?

```
file = open("decl.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
text.close()

# split oliver
words = re.split('\W+', lines)

print(words)
```

**Error Message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lab.py", line 18, in <module>
    words = re.split('\W+', lines)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/re.py", line 165, in split
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: Why are you closing text? Shouldnt that be file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file.readlines()` returns a list of all lines, you should use `file.read()`:

Always use `with` when handling files, it'll automatically close the file for you.

```
with open("decl.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
# split oliver
words = re.split('\W+', data)
```

Help on `file.read`:

```
>>> print file.read.__doc__
read([size]) -> read at most size bytes, returned as a string.

If the size argument is negative or omitted, read until EOF is reached.
Notice that when in non-blocking mode, less data than what was requested
may be returned, even if no size parameter was given.
```

Comment: My takeaway : `readlines` returns a **list** of all lines. Thanks